# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in a c++ implementation of a binary search tree

Tags: c++, xcode, class, struct, binary-search-tree

I am currently learning c++ and in order to learn it I though I would implement a simple binary search tree class in order to get a hang of the concepts in c++. When implementing an add function I am receiving an interesting error in which it seems that the program does not recognize the node as null then crashes immediately after because the node should be null.

```
//Here is my add/insert function I created.
void BinarySearchTree::insert(double x){
    if(root == NULL){
        root = (struct TreeNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode));
        root->val = x;
        return;
    }
    bool inserted = false;
    struct TreeNode* curr = root;
    while(curr != NULL && !inserted){
        if(curr->val == x){
            return;
        }
        if(x > curr->val){
            if(curr->right == NULL){
                curr->right = (struct TreeNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode));
                curr->right->val = x;
                inserted = true;
            } else {
                curr = curr->right;
            }
        } else {
            if(curr->left == NULL){
                curr->left = (struct TreeNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode));
                curr->left->val = x;
                inserted = true;
            } else {
                curr = curr->left;
            }
        }
    }
}


//This is the TreeNode struct and the BinarSearchTree class in my header file if it helps
struct TreeNode{
    double val;
    struct TreeNode *right;
    struct TreeNode *left;
};

class BinarySearchTree{
private:
    struct TreeNode *root;
public:
    void insert(double x);
};
```

Comment: You need to fix your question so that the shown code meets all requirements for a [mre], as explained in the [help], otherwise it's unlikely that anyone will be able to help you. Although I do see something in the shown code that's a near certain bug, it is not a certainty unless it can be proven, which can only be done with a [mre].

Comment: My bad fixed it up a little

Comment: The `struct` keyword is only necessary in C++ when you actually define the struct. All other times, it is unnecessary.

Comment: Also, prefer `new` to `malloc()` in C++ and prefer `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` to `new` in modern versions of C++.

Comment: I added the struct keyword after it had failed me once without it.

Comment: Just a hunch, could be related to the fact that `left` and `right` seem to not be initialized. You might want to make a constructor for `TreeNode` and set them to `nullptr`.

Comment: Yes, the shown code fails to initialize `left` and `right`. That's the reason for the crash. It also, for some reason, uses C library's `malloc`, instead of C++'s `new`. Finally, `insert()` is unnecessarily complicated and over-engineered. The classical, recursive implementatiton of `insert()` is much simpler; and it should be, maybe, ten or so lines of code. "The more you overthink the plumbing, the easier it is to stop up the drain" -- Scotty, Star Trek III.

Comment: Thanks, yea I think the issue was the lack of a constructor for the struct and c++'s new was useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grand that you are learning C++!

Have no fear: you only need to wade a little deeper in, to have it all come right. The comments concur that there is a lot yet to learn, but trust us: it will be well worth the effort.

As some comments have indicated, the major issue in this example is that you have not properly initialized the variables you are using in your decision making process, which means that they contain garbage -- any old value whatsoever -- and not the zeroes that you intend them to. Initialization is just as vital in C; C++ only holds your hand more, making sure that you do ***-- iff you let it.***

Indeed, later on you may look into the specialized pointer types that the standard library provides, but at first you may wish to just focus on learning ***the C++ way*** of doing things. You *may* use good 'ol `malloc` for allocation, but when you do you are actually just making unnecessary work for your self, and at the same time exposing your code to precisely the kind of problem you have encountered. C++ offers you `operator new`, which will do all the heavy lifting *for* you, especially when combined with a proper `constructor` function.

The simple C++ statement:

```cpp
new TreeNode;
```

... does more than it appears to. First it *allocates* the memory required for the object -- most implementations using `malloc` under the hood. Then it calls the `constructor` function you have defined for the class, to *initialize* the data in the structure.

So first, in `TreeNode` you need something along these lines:

```cpp
struct TreeNode {
   double val;
   TreeNode *right;
   TreeNode *left;

   // default constructor --'ctor'
   TreeNode():right(null), left(null) {}

   // useful ctor for your particular situation
   TreeNode( double val ):TreeNode(), val(val) {}
};
```

And then, within your `::insert` function:

```cpp
// replace these lines...
if(root == NULL){
   root = (struct TreeNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode));
   root->val = x;
   return;
} 

// with something like these...
if( !root ) {
   root = new TreeNode;   // root->val is garbage, for now
   return;
}

// and replace the two branch creation sections...
if(curr->right == NULL){
   curr->right = (struct TreeNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode));
   curr->right->val = x;
   inserted = true;
}

// ... with something like this
if( !curr->right ) {
   curr->right = new TreeNode( x );
   break;   // you are only setting 'inserted' here to end your loop
}
```

Constructors -- and the destructors that are their complements -- are powerful tools, and there are many nuances about them for you to discover.

*Then*, you can get down to the nitty-gritty of streamlining and optimizing your code.